# Theorem in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

What are the theorems that I supposed use it to prove that :

> If $\mathcal f $  is entire and $\mathcal f(z)=2f(z)$ then $ \exists $ $\lambda $ such that $\mathcal f(z)=\lambda\mathcal z$

Comment: The only  such function would be $\forall z\,f(z)=0$. Was there a typo somewhere?

Comment: I feel as if you have written the problem down incorrectly. The way you have it, $f(z)$ is $0$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Probably it should be $f(2z) = 2f(z)$.

Comment: The propblem say that the function must be linear.

Comment: But the problem does not say that $f(z)=2f(z)$! Read the comments before replying to them. Then get  the statement of the problem straight...